# How to separate digit from the output of calculation using grep

Tags: bash, grep

if assume that the output of the `command` is this:

```
7485.5
```

how do i separate the digit using grep into this:

```
7
4
8
5
```

and this output I able to manipulate it and assigned to new variable:

```
$num1=7
$num2=4
$num3=8
$num4=5
```

Comment: Why `grep`? It seems the completely wrong tool here.

Comment: you can use [bash parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion) to get individual characters from string - that might suit better than using tools like grep/cut/awk here

Comment: for example, if `7485.5` is saved in a variable `num` then `${num:2:1}` will give `8`

Comment: Do you really want multiple variables? I mean, how would you address them if you the length of the number varies? An array seems more appropriate.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I will use the parameter expansion to separate the digit.